# How to insert a new view controller in the navigation stack and then pop to it?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I want to insert a new view controller just before the view controller that is currently presented on the stack. I have tried something like this:

```
let vc: ECAssessmentVC = ECAssessmentVC.createViewController()
vc.mode = .assessmentResults
vc.quizzes = quizzes
if var vcs: [UIViewController] = navigationController?.viewControllers {
    vcs.insert(vc, at: vcs.count - 1)
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true )
}
```

However when I pop the new view controller is not showing. How would I achieve this?

Comment: That's because `vcs` won't affect `navigationController?.viewControllers`...

Answer (score 3):

You are saying this:

```
if var vcs: [UIViewController] = navigationController?.viewControllers {
    vcs.insert(vc, at: vcs.count - 1)
```

But that code, alone, is pointless. You have inserted a view controller into `vcs`, yes; but `navigationController.viewControllers` is unaffected. And then `vcs` is thrown away; it is useless.

You need to add this line:

```
    navigationController?.viewControllers = vcs
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to re assign the array

```
if var vcs: [UIViewController] = navigationController?.viewControllers {
     vcs.insert(vc, at: vcs.count - 1)
     navigationController?.viewControllers = vcs
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true )
}
```